# How to delete a line from files in subfolders using Unix commands?

Tags: unix, sed, awk, grep

I've a folder structure where the starting folder is test. test has two folders in it. test1 and test2, plus a bunch of files. There's a word welcome in these bunch of files as well as the files in test1 and test2. I tried this and it did not work

```
sed 's/\<welcome\>//g' **/*
```

What am I doing wrong? How can this be done?

Comment: What do you expect the `\<...\>` notation to do?  Does the version of `sed` do the same as you expect?  Since you have a Unix tag and not a Linux tag, you may not be using GNU `sed`, in which case that is likely to be looking for a `<welcome>` tag, not just the word `welcome` (excluding such unwelcome edits as dropping lines containing 'unwelcome' and not 'welcome' too).

Comment: Also note that the `**/*` notation is a bash4ism.  You might want to verify that your version of bash supports it., and that you have enabled the `globstar` option in your shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
find test -type f -exec sed -i '/welcome/d' '{}' \;
```

Comment: That would remove the entire line containing the word, rather than just remove the word from the line.  I didn't get that intent from the OP.

Comment: @ghoti I may be wrong but the title does says `How to delete a line...`

Comment: Ah - right you are.  Always frustrating when questions' titles don't match their content.  Well, +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this (GNU `sed`):

```
sed -i '/welcome/s/\<welcome\>//g' test/*
```

The `-i` switch modify the files, so take care.

If `-i` switch is not supported on your Unix :

```
for i in test/*; do
    sed '/welcome/s/\<welcome\>//g' "$i" > /tmp/.sed && mv /tmp/.sed "$i"
done
```

Comment: Add "&&" at the end of the sed line before the mv or you'll lose the contents of your original files if sed can't write to the tmp file.

Answer (score 1):

`sed -e 's/welcome//g' test > test2`

The file test has several entries including *welcome*.
This above sed line deletes welcome from test.

You could put it in a loop.. 
And I see that sputnick has just answered your question to a large extent! `:P`

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type f|xargs perl -ni -e 'print unless(/<welcome>/)'
```